# Stable sorting java Alphabetical order with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have been trying to run a stabel sort for the first time. I created an array which has Student Objects. Now i want to sort those objects in that array as per their name alphabetically. What i dont understand is the Arrays.sort(student,new Students());  and what should be its arguments if any. Thanks alot !

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Students implements Comparable<Students> {
private String FirstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;


public Students(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
    super();
    FirstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
}


public String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}


public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    FirstName = firstName;
}


public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}


public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}


public int getAge() {
    return age;
}


public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(Students toCheck) {
    int compareQuantity = ((Students)toCheck).getAge();

    return this.age-compareQuantity;
}



public static void main(String args[]){
    //array for the 6 students 
    Students[] student= new Students[6] ;
    //creating and adding one by one
    Students sam = new Students("Sam","Wo", 22 );
    student[0]=sam;
    Students ben = new Students("Ben","Wang", 27 );
    student[1]=ben;
    Students arsalan = new Students("Arsalan","Khan", 28);
    student[2]=arsalan;
    Students issa = new Students("Issa","Hashim", 25 );
    student[3]=issa;
    //ben khan will test if the last name is different. Should be fun .
    Students benK = new Students("Ben","Khan", 29 );
    student[4]=benK;
    Students jackM = new Students("Jack","Meth", 23);
    student[5]=jackM;

    Comparator <Students> studentCompare = new Comparator<Students>(){

    public int compare (Students s1 , Students s2){
        String studentName1 = s1.getFirstName();
        String studentName2 = s2.getFirstName();
        return studentName1.compareTo(studentName2);

        Arrays.sort(student,new Students());

    }
```

};
            for(int i =0; i

Comment: The default built-in `Arrays.sort()` are stable.

Comment: What would you want to achieve? The current `Comparator` you're using will only compare the students by first name; is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Comparator inside your main(), so you change your main() as below to make it working:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    //array for the 6 students
    Students[] student = new Students[6];
    //creating and adding one by one
    Students sam = new Students("Sam", "Wo", 22);
    student[0] = sam;
    Students ben = new Students("Ben", "Wang", 27);
    student[1] = ben;
    Students arsalan = new Students("Arsalan", "Khan", 28);
    student[2] = arsalan;
    Students issa = new Students("Issa", "Hashim", 25);
    student[3] = issa;
    //ben khan will test if the last name is different. Should be fun .
    Students benK = new Students("Ben", "Khan", 29);
    student[4] = benK;
    Students jackM = new Students("Jack", "Meth", 23);
    student[5] = jackM;

    Arrays.sort(student);

}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question ("to sort those objects in that array as per _their name alphabetically_"). The resulting sort will be _by the age_, because that's how natural ordering has been defined in the `Students` class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement Comparable interface. Try this.

```
Arrays.sort(student, new Comparator<Students>() {
      @Override
    public int compare(Students o1, Students o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return o1.FirstName.compareTo(o2.FirstName);
    }
});
```

The output is sorted alphabetically:

```
28 Arsalan
27 Ben
29 Ben
25 Issa
23 Jack
22 Sam
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8, [Comparators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) got a whole lot prettier...

```
// NOTE: I would rename your student array variable to be students
//       and your class declaration to be Student. 
Arrays.sort(student, Comparator.comparing(Students::getFirstName));
```